# Normalize data in excel

Tags: excel, data-structures

I'd like to normalize a summary sheet I've compiled. Contains several thousand rows with first three columns as criteria. Each row has anywhere from 4-1000+ columns. Example structure is as follows:

```
    Criteria1A    Criteria1B    Criteria1C    Data1a    Data1b
    Criteria2A    Criteria2B    Criteria2C    Data2a    Data2b   Data2c    Data2d
    Criteria3A    Criteria3B    Criteria3C    Data3a    Data3b    Data3c
    etc.
```

I'd like it to be like this:

```
    Criteria1A    Criteria1B    Criteria1C    Data1a
    Criteria1A    Criteria1B    Criteria1C    Data1b
    Criteria2A    Criteria2B    Criteria2C    Data2a
    Criteria2A    Criteria2B    Criteria2C    Data2b
    Criteria2A    Criteria2B    Criteria2C    Data2c
    Criteria2A    Criteria2B    Criteria2C    Data2d
    Criteria3A    Criteria3B    Criteria3C    Data3a
    Criteria3A    Criteria3B    Criteria3C    Data3b
    Criteria3A    Criteria3B    Criteria3C    Data3c
    etc.
```

(Apologies if this has been requested elsewhere in a similar form)
I am not familiar enough with VBA to has this out myself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basic functionality to reverse pivot or un pivot is this:
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2461-excel-reverse-pivot-table.html

Your multi-column criteria can be solved without vba by text-merging them into something like criteria1~criteria2~criteria3 and then split them after the standard reverse pivot approach.

Alternatively you search and understand for vba code for multi criteria reverse pivot.